Brave web browser: How to remove the 'doesn't support architecture 'i386'' message?
For Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 was installed Brave web browser according with the official instructions indicated at Release Channel Installation - Debian, Ubuntu, Mint. Therefore as follows:
sudo apt install curl

sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg

echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main"|sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list

sudo apt update

sudo apt install brave-browser

The process was successful but in that process and for each execution of the apt update command appears:
sudo apt update
...
Hit:3 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                                                
...
Fetched 3,590 B in 3s (1,411 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Observe the latest line (split in many lines for presentational purposes):
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository
'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' doesn't support
architecture 'i386'

I know it is a Note due the N: part, but being curious: How to remove the doesn't support architecture 'i386' message?

how about removing the part referring to i386 in the sources list?

Does that approach work? or is an assumption? Is safe edit that file? Or would be serious problem with an incorrect edition?

Yes well sortof.  as you found out sometimes it is --adding-- amd64 (basically you told it not to use i386 so it was not removing i)

At the /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory exists the brave-browser-release.list file where the current content is:
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main

and was upgraded to:
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main

Observe the addition of arch=amd64 and solved. It thanks to the following tutorial:

Installing Brave Browser on Linux Systems

See the Installing Brave on Ubuntu and Debian-based distributions section
